# How to integrate a download Manager (Java) with browsers like Mozila,Explorer

Tags: java, download-manager

I have created [Java Donload Manager](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B9aJ7z7JVBSNZGQzN2NmZTItN2JkZi00MTFmLTljOWItYjY0YzIxNjY1MDU3&hl=en_US) in java

Now i want to integrate it with Mozila, Internet Explorer.

Can somebody suggest me how to integrate my above code with Mozila,Explorer.

Is there any Java API that supports the same.

I am sure there is such API...I googled a lot but unable to find...

Please help me....

You suggestions are welcomed....

Comment: How should this integration look like? jDownloader for example tracks if something is copied to the clipboard. I do not know or ever heard of a direct java api in the browsers.

Comment: Integration should be such when i click download link on Mozila Browser, It should Open My programme to ask to continue with download as we see with IDM...